# How to keep a user from manually entering in a download url in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Specifically, how do I set up my .net site to not allow an unauthenticated user from manually entering in the download url and downloading content?

I have security built that requires authentication on the page where the download link is located, but should a user get access to the direct url, someone could download directly from that. Is there some logic or a plug in that can assist with this? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Just a suggestion, could you host the files in a location that is not in the the website directory, then open a file stream to the path. Then you can create a file handler to it. I'm sure there's a much better option, just trying to tink outside of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC supports the ability to create "action filters" that can be used to implement re-usable logic that can be declaratively applied to action methods.

The `[Authorize]` filter is one of the built-in action filters provided by ASP.NET MVC, and it enables a developer to declaratively apply authorization rules to action methods and controller classes.

In this action you can then read the file from disk and stream the content out.

Example:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult Download()
{
  var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\PATH\TO\PDF\ON\THE\SERVER.pdf", FileMode.Open);
  var mimeType = "application/pdf";
  var fileDownloadName = "download.pdf";
  return File(fileStream, mimeType, fileDownloadName);
}
```

Or, for a classic ASP.NET solution, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx

Sources:

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm

http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-03-17/asp_net-mvc_3-howto-stream-files-client